# Replacing characters but only once

Tags: java, replace

how do I replace a text with something else but only once because the characters may be replaced twice. For example, replacing "0123456789" to "30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39" using the .replace(/0/g,"30 ") method but when I have .replace(/3/g,"33 "), the codes become messy, how do I only replace once.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

```
String value = "0123456789";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d)");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("3$1 "));
```

**Output:**

```
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

This replace all numbers by 3 + group number 1 which is the number found here + a space.

**NB:** you have a trailing space that you can remove if needed by calling `String#trim()`